# ImportError with Python modules in Travis CI

Tags: linux, bash, travis-ci

I have a set of scripts in `.travis.yml` which runs perfectly fine at the moment

```
...
install:
- scripts/travis/install_deps.sh
- virtualenv -p /opt/pyenv/versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 venv
- source venv/bin/activate
- pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script:
- scripts/test.sh
script:
- scripts/travis/build.sh
after_success:
- deactivate
- virtualenv -p /opt/pyenv/versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 venv
- source venv/bin/activate
- pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

However, I would like to clean it up a bit so there's less repetition such that `.travis.yml` looks like

```
...
install:
- scripts/travis/install_deps.sh
- export PYTHON_VERSION=3.6
- scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh
before_script:
- scripts/test.sh
script:
- scripts/travis/build.sh
after_success:
- export PYTHON_VERSION=2.7
- scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh
...
```

where `install_python_deps.sh` looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then deactivate; fi
virtualenv -p "/opt/pyenv/versions/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION}" venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The problem arises when this is run in travis. The build breaks when `test.sh`, which runs a python script that relies on a module declared in `requirements.txt` is not found. Any pointers as to why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bizarre setup. You're running the same set of scripts for both 3.6 and 2.7?

Comment: @iBug Yes, because we have scripts `after_success` that unfortunately rely on python2

Comment: This is because after the script exits, the parent shell has not sourced the virtualenv. I would recommend looking into `tox` for testing multiple python versions.

Answer (score 0):

The `source venv/bin/activate` inside `scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh` only has effect until the script `install_python_deps.sh` exits.
If you want to use the installed modules outside the `install_python_deps.sh` script,
you need to run `source venv/bin/activate` (again) outside the script too, for example:

```
...
install:
- scripts/travis/install_deps.sh
- scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh 3.6
- source venv/bin/activate
before_script:
- scripts/test.sh
script:
- scripts/travis/build.sh
after_success:
- scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh 2.7
- source venv/bin/activate
...
```

Note that to make it shorter, I replaced the `PYTHON_VERSION` environment variable with a command line parameter. You could adjust the `scripts/travis/install_python_deps.sh` script accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

PYTHON_VERSION=$1

if [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then deactivate; fi

virtualenv -p "/opt/pyenv/versions/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION}" venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```